# What does this category theoretical notation mean?

Tags: category-theory

I've come across this notation, which I've never seen before:

[image]

This is from an article [A categorical semantics for causal structure](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04732), but I've seen it a few times before; where does this come from (where can I familiarise myself with it)?

Comment: Search for "graphical calculus" or "string diagrams" for monoidal categories. There are plenty of textbooks e.g. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-49834-8 by Turaev and Virelizier. In particular Chapter 2 for monoidal categories and 3.2 for braided categories.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore I suggest that you post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Comment: Thank you, it's now posted as an answer.

Comment: Awesome! :) $\phantom{:-)}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(As suggested, I'm posting my comment as an answer)

This notation is called "graphical calculus" or "string diagrams" for monoidal categories.

There are plenty of textbooks and depending on your background and motivation you might choose your favorite. Here is one example (I personally used most): [Turaev, Virelizier](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-49834-8). In particular Chapter 2 for monoidal categories and 3.2 for braided categories.

*Note:* Depending on the reference, there might be different conventions. For example if the diagram is read bottom to top or top to bottom or the orientation of arrows etc. Feel free to adopt your favorite one.